# C# Attributes On Fields

Tags: .net, custom-attributes

How do I set an attribute on a field anywhere in my assembly, then reflect on those field attributes in my entire assembly and get/set the field values that the attribute is attached too?

Comment: Re-tagged to remove 'c#' as this is not a language-specific question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1) Create [custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) targeted for [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx)
2) [Add it to desired fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163802.aspx)
3) Iterate through [types defined in your assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx)
4) For each [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):
4a) [iterate through it's fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx)
4b) if field [has your custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) go to step 4c
4c) [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx) or [set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z33zd7h.aspx) values of field

Comment: I wouldn't have asked here if I hadn't exhausted my search for the answer on Google and MSDN. I wasn't quite sure what too look up. Your answer points me in all the right directions, thank you!

Comment: Well, ability to search information on the web is one of the major skills of modern software developer

Comment: Yeah, but asking the correct question in the fields of copy/pasta regurgitations of the same tutorials, it's hard to find concrete answers. Again, thank you.

Comment: The hardness of using MSDN/Google for technical questions was one of the main reasons to make StackOverflow -- questions like this should be asked here.

Comment: In my case, google is as useful as my ability to guess the keywords needed to find the required information, which can be very tricky if I don't know exactly what are the keywords used in that particular area of interest.

Comment: Some people are better at it than others aku... we'll learn :) if I was high-strung, the response would seem a bit curt.

Comment: Gishu, data mining is essential skill. If you can find a way through weird code, it should not be a problem to digg google

Comment: Seeing how Stackoverflow.com is aimed at being a programmers Q&A site, I think this type of question fits quite nicely here ;-)  In theory, you could suggest the 'ol "use google next time..." approach to every single question posted here.

Comment: deadbug don't exaggerate. In this particular case Google will give you tons of useful info for a single query ".net c# custom attributes"

Comment: Well, I did use google to find out how to create my own attribute which I had completed before asking my question. Though, my problem was actually finding anything to show me how to iterate through my field attributes in my entire assembly.

Comment: Ironically, 5 years later this question is the #1 Google result for "C# accessing attributes of a field"

Comment: The link in Step 2 no longer works - just goes to a general MS Magazine site.