# VB.NET: Checking if variable is of Guid? (nullable) type

Tags: vb.net, reflection, nullable

I'm trying to check if a variable has been defined as a nullable Guid. eg.

`Dim myGuid As Nullable(Of Guid)` or `Dim myGuid As Guid?`

It seems doing a `myGuid.GetType` returns the *underlying* type, that is type Guid, not Guid?. So testing `myGuid.GetType Is GetType(Guid?)` always returns False.

How do I find out if myGuid is a nullable type?

---

Ed: I can do the following, which correctly returns True for "Guid?" and False for "Guid":

`Not Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(GetType(Guid?)) Is Nothing`

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the nullable type from the variable itself, in order to test it. I've only been able to get the underlying (non-nullable) system type.

---

Ed: Explanation of why I need to know. :)

I've written a db helper function. I pass it an object comprised of public members, representing the row data of a table. The members are the table columns.

Using reflection, I loop through these public members to create an INSERT statement for a command object and populate its parameters with the values in those members. So far so good.

But now there's a table which has a uniqueidentifier column which I must *not* populate from the row object, as it defaults to "NEWID()" (using SQL Server 2008). Instead of skipping all Guid columns, which would be easy, I only want to skip ones defined in the row data class as "Guid" (non-nullable).

Basically, I'm using the Guid? (Nullable) type to indicate it's ok to populate that uniqueidentifier column with data. If it's non-nullable, that tells me to skip it because the column has a NEWID() default value.

Hope that makes sense. If there's a better way of me knowing which guid columns to skip and which to populate, I'd be eager to know. This is just an approach I thought would be doable.

Comment: You could use an attribute instead? Mark the identifier method with a custom attribute to indicate that it should be ignored

Comment: @MarkJ, the row data class is just a bunch of public members, eg. `Public ClientFirstName As String`. Member name reflects the db column name. Is there a way of adding special attributes to a class member, in code, which can then be accessed via reflection?

Comment: Yes see these links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/71s1zwct.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw.aspx

Comment: I also recommend looking into ORM frameworks like NHibernate or the Entity Framework which could do the spadework for you.

Comment: Thanks @MarkJ, but that's about attributes applied to the class, whereas it's an individual member I want info about, not the class.

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156304/c-sharp-attributes-on-fields)

Comment: It's better to post your edit as an answer, accept it, than put the answer in the question.

Comment: @LarsTech oops, thanks that's done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! Seems it's impossible to determine if a variable alone is nullable but, as long as it's a member of a class, reflection can be used like this:

The class:

```
Public Class testclass
  Public intno As Int16
  Public intyes As Int16?
  Public guidno As Guid
  Public guidyes As Guid?
End Class
```

The code:

```
Dim oTest As New testclass
For Each f As Reflection.FieldInfo In oTest.GetType.GetFields
  Console.Write(f.Name & " is ")
  If f.FieldType.IsGenericType AndAlso f.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() Is GetType(Nullable(Of )) Then
    Console.WriteLine("Nullable")
  Else
    Console.WriteLine("Not Nullable")
  End If
Next
```

The output:

> intno is Not Nullable
>   intyes is Nullable
>   guidno is Not Nullable
>   guidyes is Nullable

Thanks to all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't care if it is a `Nullable(Of Guid)`. What you should care is if it is `null` or a `Guid` which are the 2 possible states.

Comment: @ingredient_15939, since you can't know this because that's how Nullable types work, I am asking you why you need to know this in order to provide you with an alternative approach.

Comment: @competent_tech, yes, I know that they are not nullable. But since the myGuid variable is declared as a Nullable(Of Guid) you have only two possibilities for it: It can either be null, in which case you obviously cannot know its type, or it can be a Guid. That was the point of my answer.

Comment: @Darin, No worries, I've edited the question with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Objects based on nullable types are are boxed to its underlying type if they have a value else to a null reference.

```
object o = new Nullable<Guid>(Guid.NewGuid()); //no longer a nullable guid.
```

Comment: Cheers Magnus. I found I can do it via reflection, which is great.